# How can user automatically get access to all folders above in the path?

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, permissions

How can user automatically get access to all folders above in the path?
We are having a request, when user shares a document on Sharepoint server, user can access the document via the link and the folder, but when user navigates to the library root folder, user is not able to navigate manually to that document because he/she doesn't have permission to access folders above. Is there a way to let user to manually navigate to the document  that is shared to him, because it really makes hard to users to always search for the links to be able to access the documents.

For example, the document is shared to user: Documents > Folder1 > Folder2 > Document.xslx

User is able to access Document.xslx and Folder2 using the link, but we want to make all the folders in the path visible, so the user can manually navigate to that document. Of course, we want to make only folders visible, but the other content, that user doesn't have any permissions, remains unvisible to the user.

We are using Sharepoint On-premise.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround available is to create a new view which shows all items without folder. When user only have access to the file in subfolder, still he can switch to the new view to find the document he has view permission.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is a code based solution fine?

Use a SPSecurityEventReciever and override the RoleAssignmentAdding event.

When a new user/group gets access to the item, the event fires and then we can write  SSOM code to get the parent folder and

(i) break inheritance in all child items
(ii)give permission to the user/group to the folder only.

Then , recursively traverse up to the library level and perform the above two steps.